# Webservice para streaming de video en vivo

Tags: webservice, api, stream

ojala me puedan ayudar.

Mi intensión es crear un webservice que sirva de envio de video de una camara en  vivo y consuma un API.

Existe ya creada una WS asi? o sino que me recomiendan.

Estoy iniciando en esto de la creación de web services.

Slds.